# How to partition a MySQL table on a bit column with subpartitioning on resulting partitions

Tags: mysql, partitioning, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

I am trying to figure out how to partition the following table below in MySQL database so that I have firstly 2 partitions, 1 of active users (`active` column = true) and another with non-active users.  Then I would like to sub-partition the non-active users partition by year (on the `archive_key` column with YEAR(4) as datatype).  I think I know how to achieve this, but I'm afraid to try in case I don't execute it correctly.

How can I achieve this? I currently am using both MySQL 5.7 and 8 versions.

```
CREATE TABLE users_table (
  row_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  last_name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
  createdby varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  createdat datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  lastmodby varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  lastmodat datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  active bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  archive_key year(4) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (YEAR(createdat)) STORED,
  PRIMARY KEY (row_id, active),
)
ENGINE = INNODB,
AUTO_INCREMENT = 84771,
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 166,
CHARACTER SET utf8,
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

By the way, I love the flexibility partitioning gives you! MySQL truly rocks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Subpartitioning**

MySQL is quite restrictive on what you can and cannot do when you sub-partition, quoting from [5.7 manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-subpartitions.html):

> it is possible to subpartition tables that are partitioned by RANGE or LIST. Subpartitions may use either HASH or KEY partitioning

This implies that you are looking at something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users_table (
  row_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  last_name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  createdby varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  createdat datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  lastmodby varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  lastmodat datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  active bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  archive_key year(4),
  PRIMARY KEY (row_id, active, archive_key)
)
       ENGINE = INNODB,
       CHARACTER SET utf8,
       COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
       PARTITION BY LIST(active)
           SUBPARTITION BY HASH(`archive_key`)
           SUBPARTITIONS 4
       (
            PARTITION inactive VALUES IN (0),
            PARTITION active   VALUES IN (1)
       );
```

Note that you need to include `archive_key` in the PK to avoid

> ERROR 1503 (HY000): A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function

**Opinion on partitioning**

No, it doesn't rock.  The majority of use cases presented on this forum do not run any faster with partitioning than without.  In some cases, they run slower.

Sure, there are lots of options.  The only one for which I have seen actual performance improvement is `PARTITION BY RANGE`, but even then only for narrow use cases (purging time series, 'find nearest', working set is in a single partition with 'bad' indexes, transportable tablespaces).  [*Details*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)

It is a myth that 'partition pruning' speeds up queries.  A non-partitioned table with a suitable index will probably run at least as fast.

Note: to take advantage of adding (or removing) partitioning, you must reevaluate the indexes.

In your example, nonpartitioning with

```
INDEX(active, createdat)   -- in this order

WHERE active = 1
  AND createdat >= '2017/01/01'
  AND createdat  < '2017/01/01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

or

```
INDEX(active, active_key)   -- in this order

WHERE active = 1
  AND archive_key = '2017'
```

(The former does not need the generated column.)

Comment: Thank you replying to my question but respectfully I wasn't asking for a criticism or opinion on my use case for partitioning...I've already evaluated the pros and cons/cost benefit of doing so and have opted to implement on this table after all factors have been considered.  Now if you would be kind enough to offer some help as to how to proceed with what I'm asking, i'd love to hear that.  Thank you though!  (This response is not any way meant to be mean-spirited...I just don't want your answer to dissuade others from responding to my question.)

Comment: @tfrancois - I added a `CREATE TABLE` that at least has correct syntax.